# *.do files not opening in my IE7

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer-7, struts, internet-explorer-6

I have written a struts application. When i open the application in my IE7 browser, it doesn't open the .do files, instead IE7 displayes the "FIND SAVE or CANCEL" dialog box.

Its like IE7 doesn't recognise the format. But it works well with Firefox.

Could anyone clarify why this happens with IE7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have something to do with the server, not IE (got bitten by a similar situation). Is it possible that your server isn't sending the correct content type with the response?

Your response should have a header like `Content-Type: text/html` or similar. Are you sending back HTML content or something else?

Comment: Yes i'm sending html content only. The actionforwrd goes to the jsp.

Comment: Does this JSP do something special? Do you have a Page directive <%@ page contentType="..." ... %> in there with something different than "text/html"?

Comment: This indeed sounds much like as if it is been sent with `application/xhtml` or something IE doesn't support. Indeed just use `text/html`.